# Opencv Write an image with two channel

Tags: opencv

How write a `cv::Mat` which the type is `CV_32FC2`.

Is it possible to write the two channels in TIFF file ? or write each channel separately ?

Comment: afaik 2 channel writing isnt supported in openCV, but maybe you find different library for writing TIFF?

Comment: if you're talking about imwrite, only 1,3,4 channels, also only 8bit or 16bit(tiff) images are supported

Comment: Ok. And if I would like write the two channel in two different file, how convert my image?

Comment: try `cv::split` to `std::vector<cv::Mat>` and imwrite `vector[0]` and `vector[1]` separately. To see parameters for imwrite, see: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite

Comment: Damnit micka, you beat me to it by a few seconds :(

Comment: ^^ again , would need converting to uchar and loose precision

Comment: @berak I didnt see the `CV_32FC2` constraint and was thinking only about 2 channels :D ... 16 BIT single channel would be possible though!

Comment: yes, 16 for tiff. (don't know about the flags for imwrite, though)

Comment: @artoon googling returns `libTIFF` library, but I've got no experience with that and no guarantee that it can save all TIFF formats including floating point pixel ;)

Comment: there's also Exr/Imf in opencv, meant for hdr float images, but it's not build by default(it's a beast, btw), and again, only 1,3,4 channels

Answer (score 1):

if you can live with a (large!) textfile, use the [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html):

```
Mat m; // your CV_32FC2

FileStorage fs("my.yml",FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "mat1" << m;  // key, value store
fs.release();       // flush.

FileStorage fs1("my.yml",FileStorage::READ);
fs1["mat1"] >> m;
```